# excel weighted average volume

Tags: excel, average, weighted

[image]

I was wondering how to pull a weighted average of Score1 and Score2 based on Score1 Volume and Score2 Volume. The combined score should be closer to "50" than "100" since the Score1 Volume (50) is greater than Score2 Volume (25). What would be a good weighted formula that would help derive this result. The answer should be around 60 (at least closer to 50). answer in Excel would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following (easily transferable to Excel):

```
score1 = 50
score2 = 100

score1_vol = 50
score2_vol = 25

output = (score1*score1_vol + score2*score2_vol)/(score1_vol + score2_vol)
```

Returns:

```
66.66
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper column where you multiply your weight to your values or use the sumproduct formula

This YouTube video I made shows a quick example

https://youtu.be/g_vsXp8H7Vg

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31172474)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `100` is in D2:

```
=(C2*F2+D2*G2)/(F2+G2)
```

It may be easier to comprehend with a more tangible example. Say `Score` is the number of eggs in a box and `ScoreVolume` is the number of boxes. To calculate the average number of eggs per box you need the total number of 'eggs': `(C2*F2+D2*G2)` divided by the total number of boxes: `(F2+G2)`.

Answer (score 0):

[SUMPRODUCT()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGHM3.png)

Here is another option using SUMPRODUCT().  This works well with large data sets.